# Flexbox: flex-basis: 100%; does not make a line break

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want a line break after the first select. I've tried flex-basis: 100% and width: 100%. That did not help. I also gave the html and body element a width of 100%. That did not help either. Where is my mistake?

Here is my code:

```css
html, body {
  width:100%;
}

.flex {
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
}

.flex > div {
  flex-basis:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  
  <div>
    <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
    <select name="" id="">
      <option value="loremIpsum">Lorem Ipsum</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <span>Lorem</span>
    <select name="" id="">
      <option value="lorem">Lorem</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also  need to add `flex-wrap: wrap` on Flex container element so that the flex-items can break into multiple lines, or in your case you could also just use `flex-direction: column`.

```css
.flex {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex > div {
  flex-basis:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>
    <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
    <select name="" id="">
      <option value="loremIpsum">Lorem Ipsum</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <span>Lorem</span>
    <select name="" id="">
      <option value="lorem">Lorem</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know, why align-items is here not working? I want to center vertically.      https://jsfiddle.net/e6bq0qw2/